# Performance results gets printed after every epoch

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I want to calculate the model performance, but it gets printed after each epoch even although I am computing my overall results for the training and testing dataset over all batches. My understanding that even though I have batches in my data I should get only one value for precision, recall, etc. How can I get the Precision value (as one number), recall value and performance metrics mentioned in my code for training dataset and testing dataset? What is wrong with my code?

```
def train():
    model.train()

    for data in train_loader: 
         optimizer.zero_grad() 
         model_output = my_model(data) 
         loss = criterion(model_output, data.y)  
         loss.backward()  
         optimizer.step()
```

```
def test(loader):
    output_predictions = []
    target = []
    model.eval()

    correct = 0

    for data in loader:
        model_output = my_model(data)
        predictions= model_output.argmax(dim=1)
        correct += predictions.eq(data.y).sum().item() 
        output_predictions.extend(predictions.tolist())
        target.extend((data.y).tolist())

    Acc = correct / len(loader.dataset)
    B_c = class_likelihood_ratios(target,output_predictions, labels =[0,1])
    C_R = classification_report(target,output_predictions, labels =[0,1])
    P = precision_score(target,output_predictions, labels =[0,1])
    R = recall_score(target,output_predictions, labels =[0,1])

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    PrecisionRecallDisplay.from_predictions(target,output_predictions, ax=ax)
    plt.show()

    conf_m = confusion_matrix(target,output_predictions)
    sns.heatmap(conf_m/np.sum(conf_m), annot=True, fmt='.2%', xticklabels=[1,0], yticklabels=[1,0])
    plt.show()




    #Printing the Evaluation
    print("Binary_classification_positive_and_negative", B_c)
    print(C_R)
    print(P)
    print(R)

    return Acc
```

```
for epoch in range(1, 50):
    train()
    train_results_accuracy = test(train_loader)
    test_results_accuracy = test(test_loader)
    print(f'Epoch: {epoch:03d}, Train Acc: {train_results_accuracy:.4f}, Test Acc: {test_results_accuracy:.4f}')
```

Answer (score 0):

For that you can move metrics calculation outside of the season cycle and store the results during training.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, precision_score, recall_score, confusion_matrix
from sklearn.metrics import PrecisionRecallDisplay

# Define your training and evaluation functions

def train():
    model.train()

    for data in train_loader: 
         optimizer.zero_grad() 
         model_output = my_model(data) 
         loss = criterion(model_output, data.y)  
         loss.backward()  
         optimizer.step()

def evaluate(loader):
    output_predictions = []
    target = []
    model.eval()

    correct = 0

    for data in loader:
        model_output = my_model(data)
        predictions = model_output.argmax(dim=1)
        correct += predictions.eq(data.y).sum().item() 
        output_predictions.extend(predictions.tolist())
        target.extend((data.y).tolist())

    Acc = correct / len(loader.dataset)

    return Acc, target, output_predictions

# Training loop with added monitoring

def train_and_evaluate():
    for epoch in range(1, 51):  # Changed to 51 for 50 epochs
        train()

        # Calculate metrics after training
        train_results_accuracy, train_target, train_predictions = evaluate(train_loader)
        test_results_accuracy, test_target, test_predictions = evaluate(test_loader)

        # Print and visualize metrics
        print(f'Epoch [{epoch}/{50}]')
        print(f'Train Acc: {train_results_accuracy:.4f}, Test Acc: {test_results_accuracy:.4f}')

        B_c = class_likelihood_ratios(train_target, train_predictions, labels=[0, 1])
        C_R = classification_report(train_target, train_predictions, labels=[0, 1])
        P = precision_score(train_target, train_predictions, labels=[0, 1])
        R = recall_score(train_target, train_predictions, labels=[0, 1])

        print("Binary_classification_positive_and_negative", B_c)
        print(C_R)
        print(P)
        print(R)

        # Visualizations
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        PrecisionRecallDisplay.from_predictions(train_target, train_predictions, ax=ax)
        plt.show()

        conf_m = confusion_matrix(train_target, train_predictions)
        sns.heatmap(conf_m/np.sum(conf_m), annot=True, fmt='.2%', xticklabels=[1,0], yticklabels=[1,0])
        plt.show()

# Call the train_and_evaluate function to start training and monitoring
train_and_evaluate()
```

This way, performance metrics will be calculated once after complete training, rather than evrey epoch.

Bonus: This code will train your model for 50 epochs while monitoring loss, accuracy, and other metrics at each epoch.

Comment: Thank you for your help. it did work. is there a way of looking at the loss, training and validation dataset and print them at each epoch. @Luis

Comment: Yes, you can, I'll edit my answer. @Susan

Comment: Thank you for your help, 

My question is that we didnot use output_predictions and target when computing total precision and recall. We use train_target and train_prediction, does those values automatically get the predictions/ target over the batch.
Also another question is that when I added the return loss to the train function and then added     ` print(f'Train Acc: {train_results_accuracy:.4f}, Loss : {Loss:4f} Test Acc: {test_results_accuracy:.4f}'),`  it gives loss is not defined. aslo the same happens when I try to compute the auc. @Luis